# Can't find button with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button on a web page with selenium, however, selenium can't seem to find it using different find_element methods.

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Sign in').click() 
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Sign in').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="slds-button slds-button_destructive primary-button slds-button_stretch"]').click()
```

[image]

Error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element

Does anyone know why it can't find it?

Comment: First two options won’t work. That will work only for anchor tag. Xpath one looks ok. By the way what error are you getting?

Comment: What `error` are you getting? Have you tried the `xpath` like 

`//button[normalize-space()='Sign in']`

*OR*

`//button[contains(text(),'Sign in')]`

Comment: My error was selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element, it worked with //button[contains(text(),'Sign in')] @Akzy thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try finding by class:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "slds-button slds-button_destructiveprimary-button slds-button_stretch").click()
```

Double check the class name in your HTML as I can't see the full class name.